# Condition failing for one of the clauses in a 'case' statement

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mg_ims`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_get_drop_down_data`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_get_drop_down_data`(

IN _name VARCHAR(15))

BEGIN

        CASE  

            WHEN _name = 'CUSTOMERS' THEN      

                SELECT cust_id,cust_name,address FROM tb_customers; 

            WHEN _name = 'SUPPLIERS' THEN      

                SELECT supp_name FROM tb_suppliers;

            WHEN _name = 'BRANDS' THEN 

                SELECT b.name FROM tb_brands b;

            WHEN _name = 'REGIONAL_OFFICES' THEN 

                SELECT r.name FROM tb_area_offices r;

            WHEN _name = 'SUB_OFFICES' THEN 

                SELECT s.name FROM tb_locations s;

            ELSE 

                SELECT 404 `Code`,'Case not Found' Description; 

        END CASE; 

    END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

All the above cases are working properly except 'regional_offices'... Although the syntax and logic is correct...

Comment: What is meant by not working? Are you getting any error? And which database?

Comment: **WHAT** database is this for?

Comment: mysql database ... Error is " case does not exist ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `_name` is a `varchar(15)`, but the string `'REGIONAL_OFFICES'` is 16 characters long!

Comment: Perfact... Thanks Simon McKenzie